# Difficulty with frame accuracy when generating subcaps with FFmpeg at 23.976fps

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, .srt

Difficulty with frame accuracy when generating subcaps with FFmpeg at 23.976fps

Currently testing .srt & .ass subcaps in a VFX workflow.
The goal is to drop specfic text over specific shots and the in/out points have to be frame accurate
We're working in a 23.976 project.

We're currently having no trouble using FFmpeg to generate frame-accurate subclips of individual shots from a full-show export by converting hh:mm:ss:ff to seconds and then handling the 24 to 23.976 offset (see algorithm below)

BUT when applying the same logic to subcaps using .srt & .ass files, sometimes they land perfectly on frame, and sometimes they don't.  They'll be 1 frame late at most (never early).  There's no drift overtime; the 1-frame delay does not increase over the span of the source clip.

Tech tl;dr below

The algorithm we're using:

```
InPoint_Seconds = ConvertToSeconds(InPoint_Hmsf_FullShow) - ConvertToSeconds(Start_Hmsf_FullShow) // Convert from SMTPE Time Code to seconds.
InPoint_Seconds = InPoint_Seconds * (1001 / 1000) //Handle 24 to 23.976 offset
OutPoint_Seconds = [Same idea as above]
Duration_Seconds = Output_Seconds - InPoint_Seconds
```

With that we get can subclip with perfect accuracy using the following.

```
> ffmpeg -ss InPoint_Seconds -t Duration_Seconds -i SourcePath -c copy DestPath
```

For subcaps we convert the InPoint_Seconds & OutPoint_Seconds to hh:mm:ss.ddd (for .srt) & hh:mm:ss.dd (for .ass), we get our on-again/off-again 1-frame delays.

For subcaps we convert the InPoint_Seconds & OutPoint_Seconds to hh:mm:ss.ddd (for .srt) & hh:mm:ss.dd (for .ass) as follows (all values padded for leading 0s, not shown here):

```
dd = InPoint_Seconds - parseInt(InPoint_Seconds);
ddd = Math.round(dd * 100); // for .srt
dd = Math.round(dd * 1000); // for .ass
ss = parseInt(InPoint_Seconds);
hh = parseInt(ss / (60 * 60));
ss -= (hh * 60);
mm = parseInt(ss / 60);
ss -= (mm * 60);
hmsd_srt = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss + "." + dd;
hmsd_ass = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss + "." + ddd;
```

Perhaps something in our conversion Seconds to hmsd is off?